# Is there a way to create an enumerated data type for non integers?

Tags: c++, data-structures, types, enumerated-types

I'm writing a simple conversion program and I would like to create something similar to this:

```
//Ratios of a meter
enum Unit_Type
{
  CENTIMETER = 0.01, //only integers allowed
  METER = 1,
  KILOMETER = 1000
};
```

Is there a simple data structure that will allow me to organize my data like this?

Comment: Since you're already attempting to write readable programs (which is laudable), why not go all the way and use [`std::ratio`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/ratio/ratio) for dimensionless ratios and a separate unit system for dimensionality?

Comment: @KerrekSB Don't forget [Boost.Units](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_units.html).

Comment: @Mario Sorry wrong copy/paste :) This is right: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19408305/c-floating-point-enum

Comment: Couldn't you shift the numbers so that centimeter is your base, ie: `CENTIMETER=1`, `METER=100` and `KILOMETER=100000'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. While C++11 introduces some [really neat new things for enums](http://blog.smartbear.com/c-plus-plus/closer-to-perfection-get-to-know-c11-scoped-and-based-enum-types/), e.g. specifically being able to assign them some specific internal data type (like `char`), there's no way to add floats or any other non-integer type.

Depending on what you're actually trying to do, I'd use some plain old struct for this:

```
struct UnitInfo {
    const char *name;
    float       ratio;
};

UnitInfo units[] = {
    {"centimeter",   0.01f},
    {"meter",        1},
    {"kilometer", 1000},
    {0, 0} // special "terminator"
};
```

You're then able to iterate over all your available units using a pointer as your iterator:

```
float in;
std::cout << "Length in meters: ";
std::cin >> in;

// Iterate over all available units
for (UnitInfo *p = units; *p; ++p) {
    // Use the unit information:
    //  p[0] is the unit name
    //  p[1] is the conversion ratio
    std::cout << (in / p[1]) << " " << p[0] << std::endl;
}
```

If this is about using those ratios together with actual values (like `100 * CENTIMETER`), then C++11's [user-defined literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) might be something for you:

```
constexpr float operator"" _cm(float units) {
    return units * .01f;
}
```

This could then be used like this:

```
float distance = 150_cm;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a simple data structure...

Not as simple as what you'd wanted to do with `Unit_Type`.  You can of course create a `Units_Of_Distance` class and some `const` instances called `centimetre`, `metre`, `kilometre` etc. - passing your numbers to the constructor.

If you don't feel like writing something like that from scratch, or want something more powerful, Kerrek and Angew's comments are good leads....